# regarding pointers and arrays in c language

Tags: c

I am new to C language. I have a confusion regarding pointers in C.

Here is a short program:

```
void main() {
    int *array_ptr,big_array[20];
    array_ptr=big_array;
}
```

Here when we equated pointer to the name of array then C will assign the address of first element of array to the pointer as it know that `array_ptr` is a pointer and will store an address. Whereas in this case,

```
 void main() {
     int i, *x;
     x = i;
 }
```

Here, it will throw an error. In this, we have to use `&i` to assign it to pointer `x`.
why we need to use `&` in case of integers/floats etc and don't need to use it in case of array?

Comment: The main function does not return `void`, it always returns `int`. As far as your question, [arrays decay to pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c). Any C book should have explained this.

Comment: +1. I don't know why this question receives **four** downvotes. (because of formatting?)

Comment: @ikh Perhaps because "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @chipChocolate That is a good edit, but in the future, please use inline code formatting only for *code*. The name of the language (C) is not code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that when an array name is specified without a subscript, C substitutes in a pointer to the first element of the array. Therefore, if you have an array of `int`s named `array`, then:

```
array === &array[0]
```

When used to assign to a pointer type. The difference is simply in the types -- `int` (and all of the primitive types) are treated differently than arrays, which are collections of types. So pointers work differently too, and it's simply a matter of knowing how the compiler handles them.

Comment: i got it now.thanks jackarms.

Comment: This is inaccurate. An expression of array type (including an array name) is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element in most but not all contexts. This conversion specifically happens for the indexing operator, which actually requires a pointer and an integer as its operands. One of the exceptions is the `sizeof` operator; `sizeof array` yields the size of the array, not the size of a pointer (which shows that arrays don't *always* decay to pointers).